# Pi-topCEED / Bluetooth áudio question

Tags: audio, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

I’ve a Raspberry Pi 3B+ along with a Pi-topCeed and pi-top SPEAKER ver 2. Using Raspbian Stretch not pi-top OS.
It works ok but for better quality I want to try using a Bluetooth speaker to play YouTube videos. How do I switch off the pi-topCeed speaker to use the Bluetooth one. Some times it pairs - but no sound comes from it. 
Thanks
Alastair